# Autolayout - 2 Labels with dynamic length

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a question about Autolayout - normally i dont have any problems using autolayout, if a cell label has a dynamic length - but it this case ill got 2 labels, 1 top label with a dynamic length, and a second one under the first label.

Ill tried to set to the top label a leading, trailing, a fixed width (its an ipad landscape app, so i want to have and exact with) - and to the second one a bottom, trailing, and set the leading to the first label. Like here:

[image]
[image]
[image]

But i am unable to bring that to work that:

Both labels should have an dynamic length - so update the cell height automatically. Width of both Labels is 700px, width an margin top, right and bottom is 8.

Ill forgot to say, but the left label should have a dynamic height too.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Errors after using "Lukas" Tipp:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, both labels will have a same hugging and resistance priority, making one of them less than the other would fix the problem. Ps, I'd avoid using magic numbers like 8 in your auto layout, instead use standard value

Comment: Thx for your answer - ill forgot to say that the left Label "Das ist eine Frage" also should have a dynamic length. When ill try to change to hugging and resitance priority, ill got some errors about the height of the left label too. tried to change the priority of the label to the bottom superview to "999" but that is not working. I am not sure if that works without using a "helper" view to put the bottom Label inside.

Comment: Ill post it - but ill dont want to "replace" my Frames, because label left and right (in the first line) should be on the same level.

Comment: Ok set now a bottom constraint to the superview with a priority of 999 and a height of 48 (that solved the 1 warning with the top left label)

Comment: those are not errors tho, you can use update frames and get rid of them

Comment: Ill know, but i dont want to update my frames - the label left should be on the same level as the right top label. If ill update my frames, the position is not correct anymore. So the layout should look the same like in my screenshot above.

Comment: ctrl drag from left label to right label and make their bottom aligned

Comment: Oh thanks, that worked for me! Now ill understand how to combine that constraints! Thank you very much for your help!